# Search array with regex Perl

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

```
my @array = ('Joe','Jim','Jim_BOB','Hello');
$search = "Joe";
$search2 = "Hello";
$search3 = "Jim";
$search4 =~ qw/.*?_.*?/;

my %index;
@index{@array} = (0..$#array);
my $index = $index{$search};
my $index2 = $index{$search2};
my $index3 = $index{$search3};
my $index4 = $index{$search4};
print $index,",",$index2,",",$index3,",",$index4, "\n";
```

This returns 0,3,1 which are the indexes of the $search terms in @array.  The index will not recognize $search4 however becasuse it is a regex.
My question is, how do I search @array with regex?

Comment: Side note: `qw` splits a string into a list of words, using whitespace as the delimiter. Probably not what you wanted. Also, your regex can be simplified to `/_/` (i.e. contains an underscore, anywhere in the string).

Comment: Also, be aware that because hashes cannot contain duplicate keys, this technique will only give you the *last* matching index in the case of duplicate array elements. For example, if your array is `my @array = qw(foo bar baz foo);`, then `$index{foo}` will be 3, the index of the last `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

`qw` is used to quote lists of words, to store a regex in a variable, it's better to use [`qr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qr.html):

```
my $search4 = qr/_/; # the leading and trailing '.*?' are redundant
```

Get a single arbitrary matching index:

```
my ($index4) = grep $array[$_] =~ /$search4/, 0..$#array;
```

Or all of them:

```
my @i = grep $array[$_] =~ /$search4/, 0..$#array;
```

Comment: So? The point is to search `@array`. (`%index` is simply the mechanism used to lookup the exact strings in O(N+M) instead of O(N*M).)

Comment: In order to get the first match one could use `List::Util::first()`.

Comment: using %index is faster in the exact case, but the cost to construct has to be factored in if that's the concern. It may be just as effective to /^$search1$|^$search2$|^$search3$|$search4/

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach using a hash will only return the *last* matching index if your array contains duplicate elements. Other answers have shown how you can fix your existing code, but to allow for duplicate elements, you can use [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils).

The following shows how to get the first and last matching indexes for both a fixed search string and a regex, as well as how to get all matching indexes:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use List::MoreUtils qw(first_index last_index indexes);

my @words = qw(Joe Jim Jim_BOB Hello Jim Hello Jim);

my $string = 'Jim';
my $regex = '^J';

say "First $string: " . first_index { $_ eq $string } @words;
say "Last $string: " . last_index { $_ eq $string } @words;
say "All $string: " . join ', ', indexes { $_ eq $string } @words;

say "First regex: " . first_index { /$regex/ } @words;
say "Last regex: " . last_index { /$regex/ } @words;
say "All regex: " . join ', ', indexes { /$regex/ } @words;
```

#### Output:

```
First Jim: 1
Last Jim: 6
All Jim: 1, 4, 6
First regex: 0
Last regex: 6
All regex: 0, 1, 2, 4, 6
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is the unrelated problem, in that `$search4` is not a reqex. 
`$search4 =~ qw/.*?_.*?/;` 
means that you are matching the undefined variable `$search4` against `qw/.*?_.*?/;`. `qw` is basically splitting a string on whitespace. In this case there is no whitespace and thus you are matching against the string `.*?_.*?`. In void context this has no effect at all, `$search4`is left undefined.

With `use strict; use warnings;` and after declaring your variables you would have gotten an appropriate error.

```
$ cat t1.pl 
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ('Joe','Jim','Jim_BOB','Hello');
my $search = "Joe";
my $search2 = "Hello";
my $search3 = "Jim";
my $search4 =~ qw/.*?_.*?/;

my %index;
@index{@array} = (0..$#array);
my $index = $index{$search};
my $index2 = $index{$search2};
my $index3 = $index{$search3};
my $index4 = $index{$search4};
print $index,",",$index2,",",$index3,",",$index4, "\n";

$ perl t.pl 
Use of uninitialized value $search4 in pattern match (m//) at t.pl line 8.
Use of uninitialized value $search4 in hash element at t.pl line 15.
Use of uninitialized value $index4 in print at t.pl line 16.
0,3,1,
```

I assume that you meant `$search4 = qr/.*?_.*?/`.

One solution to your problem would be to treat the regexp as a special case and to loop over your array.

```
$ cat t2.pl 
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ('Joe','Jim','Jim_BOB','Hello');
my $search = 'Joe';
my $search2 = 'Hello';
my $search3 = 'Jim';
my $search4 = qr/.*?_.*?/;

my %index;
@index{@array} = (0..$#array);
my $index = $index{$search};
my $index2 = $index{$search2};
my $index3 = $index{$search3};

# loop over the array until a match is found
my $cnt = 0;
my $index4;
for my $elem ( @array ) {
    if ( $elem =~ $search4 ) {
        $index4 = $cnt;
        last;
    }
    $cnt++;
}

print "$index,$index2,$index3,$index4\n";

$ perl t2.pl 
0,3,1,2
```

If you want to use a lookup hash, then you might like the module [Tie::Hash::Regex](http://search.cpan.org/~davecross/Tie-Hash-Regex-1.02/lib/Tie/Hash/Regex.pm) from CPAN.

```
$ cat t3.pl 
use strict;
use warnings;

# modules from CPAN
use Tie::Hash::Regex;

my @array = ('Joe','Jim','Jim_BOB','Hello');
my $search = "Joe";
my $search2 = "Hello";
my $search3 = "Jim";
my $search4 = qr/.*?_.*?/;

my %index;
tie %index, 'Tie::Hash::Regex';
@index{@array} = (0..$#array);
my $index = $index{$search};
my $index2 = $index{$search2};
my $index3 = $index{$search3};
my $index4 = $index{$search4};
print "$index,$index2,$index3,$index4\n";
bernhard@bernhard-Aspire-E1-572:~/devel/StackOverflow$ perl t3.pl 
0,3,1,2
```

Beware that there are some downsides to that solution. If multiple keys are matching, than you have no guarantee which of the matching keys you will get. And if you pass a string that does not look like a regexp, it will still be considered a regexp.

Comment: @Ben Grimm how do you make your variables with the regex case sensitive?

Comment: @JDE876 I think you meant to post this on Ben Grimm's answer, but... Regexes are *already* case sensitive by default. If you want to make them case *in*sensitive, you can use the `i` flag, e.g. `'FoO' =~ /foo/i`